# Exercise Methods of modern mathematical physics Reed Simon

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

I encountered this exercise in Methods of modern mathematical physics by Reed & Simon.
**Exercise 22 Chapter 2 Volume 1**

Let $\{ \eta_n \}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ be a set of vectors in the Hilbert space, $l_2(\mathbb{Z})$, so that $a_{nm}= \lvert \langle \eta_n, \eta_m \rangle \rvert$ is the matrix (in natural basis) of an operator $A$ on $l_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Prove that
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \| \langle f, \eta_n \rangle \|^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert \lVert f \rVert^2
$$
for any $f \in l_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Anyone willing to give a push in the right direction?

Comment: The idea of the statement is that the linear extension of $e_n\mapsto \eta_n$ ($e_n$ the standard basis of $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$) is unitarily equivalent to $A$. You can construct the unitary for example by having it act as the identity on the orthogonal complement of $\overline{\mathrm{im}(A)}$ and send $Ae_n$ to $\eta_n$ (show that this is well defined and gives a unitary). Can you see how this could help you?

Comment: The operator as I described sends $e_n \mapsto \sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty a_{nm} e_m = \sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \lvert \langle \eta_n, \eta_m \rangle \rvert e_m$. I have trouble seeing how these could be unitarily equivalent. For example in the case, $\eta_1=e_1$, $η_2 = e_1+e_2$ and all the other vectors $\eta_n$ are zero. Your map (which I will call $B$) would give $\lVert B e_1 \rVert = 1$ but my map would give $\lVert Ae_1 \rVert  = \lVert e_1 + 2(e_1+e_2) \rVert$ which is clearly not equal to 1.

Comment: You are right, I was too premature. I'll think about it. Are the components $a_{nm}$ all $≥0$ or are the absolute values in $a_{nm}=|\langle \eta_n,\eta_m\rangle|$ a typo?

Comment: No, they were not a typo. Although I suspect the same inequality will hold if you would drop them. So if you would find a way to prove that, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Ok, so without the absolute values it goes like this: If $a_{nm}=(\eta_n,\eta_m)$ and $A$ is bounded the linear extension of $e_n\mapsto \eta_n$ is bounded. Call this $B$, you have $a_{nm}=(\eta_n,\eta_m)=(B e_n,Be_m) = (e_n, B^*B e_m)$ and $A=B^*B$. Further $(f,\eta_n)=(f,Be_n)= (B^* f, e_n)$ so
$$\sum_n |(f,\eta_n)|^2=\sum_n \|\pi_n B^* f\|^2 = \|B^* f\|^2 ≤ \|B\|^2 \|f\|^2=\|A\|\,\|f\|^2$$
where $\pi_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the space spanned by $e_n$.

Comment: That indeed does the trick. Thank you, I'll try to use this to prove the other inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be seen to follow from the case in the comment.

Let $A$, $\eta_n$ be as in the question. Define $C$ to be the operator with matrix coefficients $c_{nm}=(\eta_n,\eta_m)$, this is still a bounded operator and we have seen $\sum_n |(f,\eta_n)|^2≤\|C\|\,\|f\|^2$. We want to see $\|C\|≤\|A\|$.

Let $f$ be so that $\|Cf\|≥\|C\|\,\|f\|-\epsilon$. Define $f^*:=\sum_n |f_n|\,e_n$, note $\|f\|=\|f^*\|$ and $|c_{nm}|=a_{nm}$. One has:
$$\|Cf\|^2=\sum_n \left|\sum_m c_{nm}\,f_m\right|^2≤\sum_n\left(\sum_m |c_{nm}\,f_m|\right)^2=\|Af^*\|^2$$
it follows:
$$\|Af^*\|≥\|C\|\,\|f\|-\epsilon = \|C\|\,\|f^*\|-\epsilon$$
this holds for any $\epsilon$, so $\|A\|≥\|C\|$.

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you.